# Need GIT command to list out the associated commits in TFS build

Tags: git, powershell, github, tfs

I have Rolling build (Batched CI BUILD) which runs for every commit.

I want to write a PowerShell script which gives us the associated commits details to that build.

I need exact Git command to get these details.

Would someone help me to get this command?

Comment: What do you mean by "commit details"?

Comment: Changes which are included in that commit. Like what are the changes are involved in that commit and on which file changes are happend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Builds - Get Build Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API.

PowerShell script for example:

```
$buildId = 1999
$url = http://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{teamProject}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)/changes?api-version=3.0

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials

Write-Host "The associated commits to build $($buildId): `n"

For ($i=0; $i -le $response.count - 1; $i++) 
{
    Write-Host "Commit ID: $($response.value[$i].id)"
    Write-Host "Commit Message: $($response.value[$i].message)"
    Write-Host "Commit Author: $($response.value[$i].author.displayName)"
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

Results:

```
The associated commits to build 1999: 

Commit ID: c7d9318beda3950c1aa1b2c63f3a8ecf7
Commit Message: added platform x64
Commit Author: Shayki Abramczyk
------------------------------------------------------
Commit ID: e4a3e6cc4c118a9ffa936a5bf24b0c74
Commit Message: added check to verify tests
Commit Author: John Doe
------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to see more details, you can use [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API:

The above script improved:

```
$buildId = 1999
$url = http://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{teamProject}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)/changes?api-version=3.0

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ContentType application/json -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials

Write-Host "The associated commits to build $($buildId): `n"

For ($i=0; $i -le $response.count - 1; $i++) 
{
    Write-Host "Commit ID: $($response.value[$i].id)"
    Write-Host "Commit Message: $($response.value[$i].message)"
    Write-Host "Commit Author: $($response.value[$i].author.displayName)"
    Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------"

    $changesUrl = "http://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{teamProject}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/$($response.value[$i].id)/changes?api-version=3.0"
    $changes = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $changesUrl -ContentType application/json -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials

    Write-Host Commits changes:
    For ($j=0; $j -le $changes.changeCounts.Edit; $j++) 
    {

    Write-Host $changes.changes[$j].item.path
    Write-Host $changes.changes[$j].changeType `n
    }

}
```

Results:

```
Associated commits to build 1999014: 

Commit ID: c7d9318beda3950c1aa1b2c63f3a8ecf74be26c3
Commit Message: added platform independent file separator
Commit Author: Kedar Kale
------------------------------------------------------
Commits changes:
/Server
edit 

/Server/parent/cognos2/package-cognos2/src/main/java/com/y/ModelController.java
edit 


Commit ID: e4a3e6cc4c118a9ffa936a5bf24b0c744b71b5b6
Commit Message: added check to verify BMT File Path for PathManipulation Fortify issue
Commit Author: Kedar Kale
------------------------------------------------------
Commits changes:

/Server/parent/cognos2
edit 

/Server/parent/cognos2/package-cognos2/src/main/java/com/y/ModelController.java
edit
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

By the above command It will give the basic details like "Commit ID"  "Commit messages". Can you please tell me how to get details of those commits. Complete details of associated commits like what are the changes done in those commits and on which folder/file changes are done.

Comment: 1) I am giving it  $buildId = $(Build.BuildNumber). Am i giving correctly?(line 1)

2)http://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{teamProject}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)/changes?api-version=3.0 


I tried manually to access the abve url bt it alwys says url not found and
 In my tfs web I can see http://{tfsServer}:8080/tfs/{collection}/{teamProject}/__build/results?buildId=696 but not the url which starts with "_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)/changes?api-version=3.0"
Where I can see this "_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)/changes?api-version=3.0" Url How can I access it??